# Get a setting value conditionally in the Customizer api

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

I'm doing this the normal way, instead of refresh I edit the element with JS according to the user selection, but in one case, I need a value that depends on another value and I can't get that.

Here's my JS:

```
wp.customize( 'myplugin[border_width]', function( value ) {
 value.bind( function( to ) {
    window.border_style ='';
    window.border_color ='';

    wp.customize( 'myplugin[border_style]', function( value ) {
       value.bind( function( to ) {
          border_style = to;
       } );
    } );
    wp.customize( 'myplugin[border_color]', function( value ) {
       value.bind( function( to ) {
          border_color = to;
       } );
    } );

    if ( !empty(to) ) {
       console.log(to); // works
       console.log(border_style); // empty
       console.log(border_color); // empty
    }
 } );
} );
```

Both the style and color values are empty always, even when I change them in the customizer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but you can use `wp.customize.get()` to get all the currently set Customizer settings:

```js
var settings = wp.customize.get(); // get all settings
var border_style = settings['myplugin[border_style]'];
var border_color = settings['myplugin[border_color]'];

// Or, this works, too.
var border_style = wp.customize.get()['myplugin[border_style]'];
var border_color = wp.customize.get()['myplugin[border_color]'];
```

[Reference](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentynineteen/1.4/js/customize-preview.js#L21)